# Show that if $n≥2$ , ${n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)\over k!} \left({1\over n}\right)^k<{1\over k!}$

Tags: inequality

I am doing revision for the mid-term exam, and i have difficulty to deal with this problem from the text book.

Show that if $n≥2$ , $${n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)\over k!} \left({1\over n}\right)^k<{1\over k!}$$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $k!$.

Answer (score 3):

This is really equivalent to showing that

$$\frac{n(n - 1) ... (n - k + 1)}{n^k} < 1$$

(Why?) But this is true because the numerator consists of $k$ terms multiplied together, each of which is strictly less than $n$ (except for the first, of course), divided by $k$ terms which are each $n$. That is, we can group it as

$$\left(\frac{n}{n}\right) \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right) \left(\frac{n - 2}{n}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{n - (k - 1)}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1)$ is the permutation function $P(n, k)$.  So your question is:

$$P(n, k) < n^k$$

You'll note this isn't actually true for $k=1$, since $P(n, 1) = n$.  I suspect your question has a typo, and you actually want $k \ge 2$, not $n \ge 2$.

Let's try induction on k.

Base case for k = 2:
$$P(n, 2) < n^2$$
$$n \cdot (n - 1) < n\cdot n$$

Inductive assumptions:
$$P(n, k) < n^k$$
$$k > 2$$

Recursive case:
$$P(n, k+1) < n^{k+1}$$
$$P(n, k) \cdot (n - k) < n \cdot n^k$$
Apply the first inductive assumption, and the fact that $(n - k) < n$ due to the second inductive assumption.  Left side less than right side, QED.